# Parse this CSV file and create without using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was able to figure out how to do this with Pandas, but without, I'm totally lost: I'm given two CSV files:

order_products:

```
order_id,product_id,add_to_cart_order,reordered
2,33120,1,1
2,28985,2,1
2,9327,3,0
2,45918,4,1
3,17668,1,1
3,46667,2,1
3,17461,4,1
3,32665,3,1
4,46842,1,0
```

products:

```
product_id,product_name,aisle_id,department_id
9327,Garlic Powder,104,13
17461,Air Chilled Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts,35,12
17668,Unsweetened Chocolate Almond Breeze Almond Milk,91,16
28985,Michigan Organic Kale,83,4
32665,Organic Ezekiel 49 Bread Cinnamon Raisin,112,3
33120,Organic Egg Whites,86,16
45918,Coconut Butter,19,13
46667,Organic Ginger Root,83,4
46842,Plain Pre-Sliced Bagels,93,3
```

I'm to then create a new table that lists for each department, the number of orders created for this department, the number of first orders, and the ratio of (number of first orders / number of orders) for that department

So the resulting table would look like:

```
department_id,number_of_orders,number_of_first_orders,percentage
3,2,1,0.50
4,2,0,0.00
12,1,0,0.00
13,2,1,0.50
16,2,0,0.00
```

My solution involving Pandas:

```
orders = pd.read_csv("../insight_testsuite/tests/test_1/input/order_products.csv")
products = pd.read_csv("../insight_testsuite/tests/test_1/input/products.csv")

orders.drop(['add_to_cart_order'], axis=1, inplace=True)
products.drop(['aisle_id', 'product_name'], axis=1, inplace=True)

dep = pd.merge(orders, products)

dep = (dep.groupby('department_id')['reordered']
         .agg([('number_of_orders','size'), 
               ('number_of_first_orders', lambda x: x.eq(0).sum())
               ])
         .reset_index())

dep['percentage'] = ("%.2f" % 
   round((dep['number_of_first_orders'] / dep['number_of_orders']), 2))
```

But with regular Python, AFAIK, you can only go through the CSV file line by line and evaluate from there. So I'm not sure how you can perform that kind of analysis without using Pandas.

Comment: I would try reading the csv file into a list of dictionaries, where each element in the list is a row of the table.

Comment: Even then, how do you emulate Pandas aggregate functions?

Comment: Unless you really have to, I wouldn't bother. Don't reinvent the wheel as they would say. If a library for a specific purpose exists use the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can. It just takes a lot of work:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

s1 = '''order_id,product_id,add_to_cart_order,reordered
2,33120,1,1
2,28985,2,1
2,9327,3,0
2,45918,4,1
3,17668,1,1
3,46667,2,1
3,17461,4,1
3,32665,3,1
4,46842,1,0'''
s2 = '''product_id,product_name,aisle_id,department_id
9327,Garlic Powder,104,13
17461,Air Chilled Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts,35,12
17668,Unsweetened Chocolate Almond Breeze Almond Milk,91,16
28985,Michigan Organic Kale,83,4
32665,Organic Ezekiel 49 Bread Cinnamon Raisin,112,3
33120,Organic Egg Whites,86,16
45918,Coconut Butter,19,13
46667,Organic Ginger Root,83,4
46842,Plain Pre-Sliced Bagels,93,3'''
result = '''department_id,number_of_orders,number_of_first_orders,percentage
3,2,1,0.50
4,2,0,0.00
12,1,0,0.00
13,2,1,0.50
16,2,0,0.00'''

lines = s1.split('\n')
# lines
# ['order_id,product_id,add_to_cart_order,reordered', '2,33120,1,1', '2,28985,2,1', '2,9327,3,0', '2,45918,4,1',
#  '3,17668,1,1', '3,46667,2,1', '3,17461,4,1', '3,32665,3,1', '4,46842,1,0']

splitlines = [x.split(',') for x in lines]
# splitlines
# [['order_id', 'product_id', 'add_to_cart_order', 'reordered'], ['2', '33120', '1', '1'], ['2', '28985', '2', '1'],
#  ['2', '9327', '3', '0'], ['2', '45918', '4', '1'], ['3', '17668', '1', '1'], ['3', '46667', '2', '1'],
#  ['3', '17461', '4', '1'], ['3', '32665', '3', '1'], ['4', '46842', '1', '0']]

orders = {}
for j, k in enumerate(splitlines[0]):
    orders[k] = [int(splitlines[i][j]) for i in range(1, len(splitlines))]

# orders
# {'order_id': [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4], 'product_id': [33120, 28985, 9327, 45918, 17668, 46667, 17461, 32665, 46842],
#  'add_to_cart_order': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1], 'reordered': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]}

lines = s2.split('\n')
# lines
# ['product_id,product_name,aisle_id,department_id', '9327,Garlic Powder,104,13',
#  '17461,Air Chilled Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts,35,12',
#  '17668,Unsweetened Chocolate Almond Breeze Almond Milk,91,16', '28985,Michigan Organic Kale,83,4',
#  '32665,Organic Ezekiel 49 Bread Cinnamon Raisin,112,3', '33120,Organic Egg Whites,86,16', '45918,Coconut Butter,19,13',
#  '46667,Organic Ginger Root,83,4', '46842,Plain Pre-Sliced Bagels,93,3']
splitlines = [x.split(',') for x in lines]
# splitlines
# [['product_id', 'product_name', 'aisle_id', 'department_id'], ['9327', 'Garlic Powder', '104', '13'],
#  ['17461', 'Air Chilled Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts', '35', '12'],
#  ['17668', 'Unsweetened Chocolate Almond Breeze Almond Milk', '91', '16'],
#  ['28985', 'Michigan Organic Kale', '83', '4'], ['32665', 'Organic Ezekiel 49 Bread Cinnamon Raisin', '112', '3'],
#  ['33120', 'Organic Egg Whites', '86', '16'], ['45918', 'Coconut Butter', '19', '13'],
#  ['46667', 'Organic Ginger Root', '83', '4'], ['46842', 'Plain Pre-Sliced Bagels', '93', '3']]
products = {}
for j, k in enumerate(splitlines[0]):
    products[k] = [splitlines[i][j] for i in range(1, len(splitlines))]

# products
# {'product_id': ['9327', '17461', '17668', '28985', '32665', '33120', '45918', '46667', '46842'],
#  'product_name': ['Garlic Powder', 'Air Chilled Organic Boneless Skinless Chicken Breasts',
#                   'Unsweetened Chocolate Almond Breeze Almond Milk', 'Michigan Organic Kale',
#                   'Organic Ezekiel 49 Bread Cinnamon Raisin', 'Organic Egg Whites', 'Coconut Butter',
#                   'Organic Ginger Root', 'Plain Pre-Sliced Bagels'],
#  'aisle_id': ['104', '35', '91', '83', '112', '86', '19', '83', '93'],
#  'department_id': ['13', '12', '16', '4', '3', '16', '13', '4', '3']}

departments = list(set(products['department_id']))
# departments
# ['13', '16', '12', '3', '4']


order_counts = defaultdict(int)
for thing in products['department_id']:
    order_counts[thing] += 1

# order_counts
# defaultdict( < class 'int'>, {'13': 2, '12': 1, '16': 2, '4': 2, '3': 2})

report = {}
departments.sort(key=lambda x: int(x))
# departments
# ['3', '4', '12', '13', '16']
report['department_id'] = departments
report['number_of_orders'] = [order_counts[dep] for dep in report['department_id']]
# report
# {'department_id': ['3', '4', '12', '13', '16'], 'number_of_orders': [2, 2, 1, 2, 2]}
first_order_count = defaultdict(int)
department_product = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(products['product_id'])):
    if products['department_id'][i] in departments:
        department_product[products['department_id'][i]].append(products['product_id'][i])

# department_product
# defaultdict( <class 'list'>, {'13': ['9327', '45918'], '12': ['17461'], '16': ['17668', '33120'], '4': ['28985', '46667'], '3': ['32665', '46842']})

order_first_counts = defaultdict(int)

product_department = {}
for dep, prodlist in department_product.items():
    for prod in prodlist:
        product_department[prod] = dep

# product_department
# {'9327': '13', '45918': '13', '17461': '12', '17668': '16', '33120': '16', '28985': '4', '46667': '4', '32665': '3',
#  '46842': '3'}

first_order_count = defaultdict(int)
for prod, reordered in zip(orders['product_id'], orders['reordered']):
    if product_department[str(prod)] in departments and int(reordered) == 0:
        first_order_count[product_department[str(prod)]] += 1
# first_order_count
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'13': 1, '3': 1})

report['number_of_first_orders'] = [first_order_count[dep] for dep in report['department_id']]
report['first_order_ratio'] = [q[0] / q[1] for q in zip(report['number_of_first_orders'], report['number_of_orders'])]
# report
# {'department_id': ['3', '4', '12', '13', '16'], 'number_of_orders': [2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
#  'number_of_first_orders': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 'first_order_ratio': [0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0]}
reportdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(report)

#   department_id  number_of_orders  number_of_first_orders  first_order_ratio
# 0             3                 2                       1                0.5
# 1             4                 2                       0                0.0
# 2            12                 1                       0                0.0
# 3            13                 2                       1                0.5
# 4            16                 2                       0                0.0
```

Presented for your amusement. I may come back and put some strategic comments in where I built dictionaries to represent FKeys and so on

Cheers!